# PyCharm, синхронизировать с git на локальной ПК и сервере

Tags: python, git, pycharm

Использую `PyCharm` и удаленный сервер для разработки с помощью функции `deployment` в `PyCharm`, но иногда возникают проблемы с файлами миграции и при переключении между ветками возникают куча проблем, потому как приходиться переключать сразу 2 раза, на локальной машине и на сервере еще сбрасывать все изменения на сервере перед сменой ветки.

Вопрос: Как можно синхронизировать `git` на локальной ПК и на сервере или возможно есть други пути решения?

Comment: А зачем использовать удаленный сервер для разработки, на локальной машине не получается?

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов это просто удобнее, да и работает он пошустрее чем локальная машина, да и интернет канал побольше

Comment: **sshfs** + `git worktree`.

Comment: @0andriy хм, если я вас понят, то есть примонтируем нашу папку с проектом к локальной машине и с `git worktree` на локальной машине мы синхронизируем действия в 2 дериктория?

Comment: `git worktree` при попытке работы с индексом будет считывать или сохранять объекты удалённо, в то время как рабочее дерево, которое вы редактируете и компилируете будет локально, т.е. быстро и без сети!

Comment: @0andriy хм, то есть нужно 2 ветки локальная и удалённая и каждая существует отдельно но можно быстро их слить? (Если я так все понял) но мне все же интересно работа в 1 ветке, проект на Django + Celery (не считая БД) и очень развесистый и очень редко запускаю его на локальной машине.

Comment: Да, примерно так. Можно сказать что это эмуляция Git-сервера для бедных. А вот уж избавиться от двух веток у вас не получится никак (кроме случая вы **единственный** разработчик, работаете непосредсвенно в **одном** месте).

Comment: @0andriy да, это понятно, но когда нужно синхронизироваться девелопер ветку локальную и на девелоперском сервере (если учесть что есть отдельная виртуальный сервер под эти задачи и изменения в файлах соответствуют файлам на локальной машине)